# What's more optimized in a list: several items with one number each, or one item with a string containing several numbers?

Tags: list, rest, custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api, optimization

I'm using a Sharepoint list to keep track of items that users have favorited, mapping user aliases to item IDs. I have two options, and I'm wondering which is more efficient. One makes for less total items in the list, but the other takes less processing per operation- I'm wondering if either of these considerations are negligible in terms of SharePoint.

#### Option 1:

Create a new item with one user alias and one ID number every time an item is favorited, removing it when un-favorited.

#### Option 2:

Check if an item with the user's alias exists. If it does not, create a new item with the alias and the item's ID. If it does, append the item ID after the previous IDs associated with the user's alias. When removing a favorite, that particular ID needs to be located in the list of IDs and removed.

Comment: 1. I think you meant to flip the wording in your option 2... If an item with the user's alias exists, **append**, and if it doesn't, **create a new item**.

2. With the first option you would probably run up against the 5,000 list item soft cap in SharePoint much faster, unless your number of users and/or items to favorite isn't that significant. If you do go with option 2, consider reordering the items in sequence each team you append/delete to make it faster to cycle through.

Comment: wording fixed as per your note (good catch). I wasn't aware of the 5,000 item cap— it will likely not come even close to that mark, but I may go with option 2 just in case. Thank you!